# What is the correct way to join two tables in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables.  The first table holds simple user data and has the columns

```
$username, $text, $image
```

(this is called "USERDATA").

The second table holds information about which users "follow" other users, which is set up with the columns

```
$username and $usertheyfollow
```

(this is called "FOLLOWS").

What I need to do is display the data individually to each user so that it is relevant to them.  This means that userABC for instance, needs to be able to view the `$text` and `$image` inputs for all of the users whom he/she follows.  To do this, I believe I need to write a sql query that involves first checking who the logged in user is (in this case userABC), then selecting all instances of `$usertheyfollow` on table FOLLOWS that has the corresponding value of `"userABC."`  I then need to go back to my `USERDATA` table and select `$text` and `$image` that has a corresponding value of `$usertheyfollow`.  Then I can just display this using echo command or the like...

How would I write this SQL query?  And am I even going about the database architecture the right way?

Comment: if homework, you should indicate that.  this is a simple select statement, please try to create one then ask for help.

Comment: Also, for homework questions especially, please note what you have tried so far. That will help people tailor their answers to address your specific problems.

Comment: "*What is the correct way to join two tables in SQL?*". The simple answer is to use ***join***. What else are you looking for?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: Not homework, just very new at this.  Thanks for commenting regardless.  I appreciate the understanding and patience.  Trust me, I am working very hard to learn, and these answers are invaluable.  Jams was able to describe what I needed.  Thanks guys.  Cfreak, thanks for editing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, neither of these answers were right.  @jam6459 was closest.

The correct answer is the following:

```
SELECT userdata.text, userdata.image, follows.userFollow
  FROM userdata
  LEFT JOIN follows ON follows.userFollow = userdata.username
  WHERE follows.userId = $username
```

I also found it easier to not have a username correspond to an Id as in jam's table example.  This is because the same user can have multiple entries in "USERDATA".  I instead used username as the Id.

Comment: go ahead and select your own answer as the correct answer, it will help people in the future.

Answer (score 2):

With tables like so:

`userdata` table

```
 ______________________________
| id | username | text | image |
|------------------------------|
| 1  | jam      | text | image |
+------------------------------+
| 2  | sarah    | text | image |
+------------------------------+
| 3  | tom      | text | image |
+------------------------------+
```

`follows` table

```
 _____________________
| userId | userFollow |
|---------------------|
|   1    |     2      |
+---------------------+
|   1    |     3      |
+---------------------+
```

and use the following SQL:

```
SELECT userdata.text, userdata.image FROM follows LEFT JOIN userdata ON follows.userFollow = userdata.id WHERE follows.userId = 1
```

will get all the text and images that user with id '1' follows

Comment: Thanks for answering and spelling this out exactly. This is precisely what I needed.  This was different than I was going about it before.  And thanks for not being rude in your response.  Means a lot to a beginner like myself!

Comment: Jam, I am having trouble with this code.  My first question is:  where in the query does it reference the table "userdata"?  Or does it not have to?

Secondly, you have "LEFT JOIN userFollow ON follows.usertheyfollow".  Neither of your example tables have the column "usertheyfollow", so is this still right?

Comment: sorry I have changed the sql so that it will fit the table names/fields.

Answer (score -1):

```
function get_text_image($username)
{
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM USERDATA where username='".$username."'";  
     $result = mysql_query($sql);

     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
         echo $row['text'];
         echo $row['image'];
     }
}



function display_data_of_followers($userid)
{
     $sql = "SELECT usertheyfollow FROM follow WHERE userid = ".$userid."";
     $result = mysql_query($sql);

     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
          get_text_image($row['usertheyfollow']);
     }
}

display_data_of_followers($userid);
```

Comment: Such SQL statements are vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: -1, not a valid answer to the question and a poor and dangerous implementation.